# autolayout for an image and a label

Tags: objective-c, swift, autolayout

I am currently trying to layout an image beside a label. I would like the label to have the intrinsic height, and the image dimensions match this intrinsic height. Then the labels width should fill. So something like this:

If the label is 10px high (intrinsic height due to fonts, etc), then the image should be 10px by 10x, and the label width should extend.

For my auto layout constraints, I have set the following:

on the image:

- top and leading edge pinned to superview
- match dimension for height and width to label's height

on the label:

- top, bottom and trailing edge pinned to superview
- leading edge pinned to image
- compressing resistance priority for vertical axis

So here's the thing:

When I lay out my view without a image loaded into uiimageview.image, everything lays out perfectly. When I set my image later, the image fits in the 10x10 box.

However, if I set my image first (let's say the image is 40x40), and then I lay out my view, then for some reason the image view has priority. As a result, the image view is 40x40, and the label's height is 40 to match!

**I want the intrinsic height of the label to have priority over the image's height in the image view.**

How do I get that to work? Right now, my work around is to never set the image before layout - but that seems like i'm hacking around something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the image view is resisting compressing its content at a higher priority than the label is resisting expanding beyond the size necessary for its content. You need to reverse that.

You need to set the Compression Resistance priority on the image view to be lower than the vertical Content Hugging priority of the label. Lower the former and/or increase the latter.